# How to read data from Hive without Spark

Tags: java, hive, hive-metastore

I need to know is there any data in Hive or not. Is there a way to execute queries(like "`select * from table_name limit 1`") or read data in another way from Hive but without Spark using only java standalone app? I know where files locations but I don't know their structure or format. And write solutions for each format seems not really good idea.
I have Kerberos Auth

Comment: if file exists - there is some data. If table contains no rows - no data files exist. Checking files exist can be much faster

Comment: .parquet file, for example, can exist but without any value inside. Just empty scheme

Comment: Agree, it can happen if file is created not by hive

Answer (score 0):

Try using JDBC driver, like this:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
 
public class HiveClient {
    private static String driverClass = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName(driverClass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException exception) {
 
            exception.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://", "", "");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
 
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " LIMIT 1";
        result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        if (result.next() == false) {
        System.out.println("Result is empty");
        } else {
          ... Do something else

        }

        result.close();
 
        statement.close();
 
        connection.close();
 
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I have kerberos auth